# Integrating Cachely add-on with Django on Heroku

Tags: django, caching, heroku

I have installed the Cachely addon on the app, and received my CACHELY_URL. The [devcenter article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cachely) gives instructions about how to integrate the addon in a rails environment.

My app uses a Django environment. Is there any documentation on how to integrate the app in a Django environment? Is there a better way to have caching in a Django environment on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I had a chat with their support team, and they communicated to me that they are being shut down by the end of the year. So, looks like I should move on to some other add-on.